# PHP "continue" targetting "break" while trying to import a wordpress site in local

Tags: php, wordpress, import

Hi (or hi again cause i asked a question but it was a bit bad explained and overall i was misunderstanding the problem).

I'm tryin to import manually a wordpress site in local. I had first trouble to link my database with the site because i was using mariaDB and the site MySQL but this is ok now.

I have now PHP errors displaying :

```
( ! ) Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-includes\pomo\plural-forms.php on line 210
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  407568  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0007  407912  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:17
3   0.0012  408832  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-load.php' ) ...\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0016  409632  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-config.php' )   ...\wp-load.php:37
5   0.0030  411184  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-settings.php' ) ...\wp-config.php:95
6   0.0372  730712  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-includes\pomo\mo.php' )  ...\wp-settings.php:102
7   0.0382  733336  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-includes\pomo\translations.php' )   ...\mo.php:10

( ! ) Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\operations.class.php on line 5467
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  407568  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0007  407912  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:17
3   0.0012  408832  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-load.php' ) ...\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0016  409632  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-config.php' )   ...\wp-load.php:37
5   0.0030  411184  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-settings.php' ) ...\wp-config.php:95
6   0.5117  5808072 include_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\revslider.php' )  ...\wp-settings.php:305

( ! ) Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\operations.class.php on line 5475
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  407568  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0007  407912  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:17
3   0.0012  408832  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-load.php' ) ...\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0016  409632  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-config.php' )   ...\wp-load.php:37
5   0.0030  411184  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-settings.php' ) ...\wp-config.php:95
6   0.5117  5808072 include_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\revslider.php' )  ...\wp-settings.php:305

( ! ) Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\output.class.php on line 7357
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  407568  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0007  407912  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:17
3   0.0012  408832  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-load.php' ) ...\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0016  409632  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-config.php' )   ...\wp-load.php:37
5   0.0030  411184  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-settings.php' ) ...\wp-config.php:95
6   0.5117  5808072 include_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\revslider.php' )  ...\wp-settings.php:305

( ! ) Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\operations.class.php:5467) in C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1216
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  407568  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0007  407912  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\www\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:17
3   1.9924  32967368    wp( )   ...\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   1.9924  32967368    WP->main( ) ...\functions.php:960
5   2.0027  28820312    do_action_ref_array( )  ...\class-wp.php:726
6   2.0027  28820312    WP_Hook->do_action( )   ...\plugin.php:515
7   2.0027  28820312    WP_Hook->apply_filters( )   ...\class-wp-hook.php:310
8   2.0453  28920216    rsssl_front_end->wp_redirect_to_ssl( )  ...\class-wp-hook.php:286
9   2.0453  28920264    wp_redirect( )  ...\class-front-end.php:105
10  2.0458  28920328    header ( )  ...\pluggable.php:1216
```

So what i know is that it is a PHP version problem, and it can be fixed by writing "continue 2" instead. But the problem is i heard that it wasn't a solution to modify the code in a wordpress site because it could breake the site in some ways. What can i do? does someone have any idea? On ovh i can see it uses PHP7, same on Wamp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes, this deprecated code in php 7.3+, and you have to go through each line and replace 'continue' to 'break' in order to stop warnings

for  headers already sent , this will fix it self if you have no warnings.

Another a bit dirty solution is to add `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);` somewhere near the top in index.php

Comment: Another "dirty" solution is just to ignore them - they're warnings, they can be ignored if things are working. DON'T change to `continue 2`, that will change the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the site is not displaying at all so i guess that those warnings are blocking something. But if i have the same PHP version why does it happen?

Comment: try inserting `output_buffering = 4096` inside php.ini and restart server

Comment: It didn't work. You meant the php.ini inside the bin folder ? I had 3 php version, maybe i should switch to the same version that is on OVH ?

Comment: I changed "continue" to "break", but i had a problem where localhost would load but not "localhost/thiswebsite". All my projects are loading correctly except this one, i have a "err_connection_refused" message, the site can't be reached